# Stateful and Stateless Components

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

As far as i know, nowadays, react functional components have a lot more cases of usages than class ones. And performing Stateful and Stateless principle in functional components while using hooks, sometimes are not possible (Isn't it?). So, this principle is not used with functional components or not?

Comment: ...what? Function-based components have been able to be stateful since the introduction of _hooks_, they can do the same things with (or without) state class-based components can.

Comment: I mean, I just watched a video in coursera react course, and it stated there that you should have a stateful component that operates data, states and other 'stateless' ui representing components. So, stateless should only draw jsx and return it, but if you are using, for example, useState hook inside stateless component, by logic, it stops being stateless. So, you somehow need to... Forget, I kind of understood. Still, isn't it bad to use, for example, setState() in that common stateful component, when it only should be scoped inside child component?